# Best way to add data to a list in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database and was trying to store a list of "Animales" for a user.

Database structure:

[image: Database structure link]

What I want to achieve is that for example: for the user with "Uuid" 11111 a list with the animals that he is publishing appears. I mean:

```
Fireabase-root
    |
    --- 11111
          |
          --- animal1 
                |
                --- descripcion: "algo"
                |
                --- edad: "algo"
                |
                --- nombre: "algo"
                |
                --- raza: "algo"

           --- animal2
               ...
           --- animal3
               ...
```

I wanted to know what is the best way to do this. I thought that the child "animal1" is a key and for each animal that is generated a different key is added, but I don't know if this is the best way to solve it. I tried to try with the push method that I saw that generates a key, but I don't know how to use it. I leave what I was testing.

```
DatabaseReference nombre = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Animales").child(userId).push().child("nombre");
nombre.setValue("Leon");
```

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: The code looks fine to me at first glance. When you run this code, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of Animals you have compared to the number of users is smaller, then what you can do is, under the root-node, form a node called `Animals`, and whenever a new animal is created you add it there.

Again under the root-node form a child-node called `users`, and inside that you add `user1`,`user2`, etc...
Now each time a user is associated with an animal you create a new child-node under that user and add just the name of the animal from the `Animals` node. When you need to access the properties of those animals just refer to their information from `Animals`.

This makes the tree way shorter, and I think it is a more elegant way of doing it, instead of creating the same animal repeatedly for different users.